# Deploying multi layer Docker image to Kubernetes with AWS ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes

I have the following manifest and the `diff` files. I believe "docker import" will create an image from each individual layer, but I need to deploy them all together somehow. The internal repo to be used is AWS ECR. Or is there another way?

Could I merge this into a single docker image that can be deployed to Kubernetes (with Helm or kubectl)?

```
{
   "schemaVersion": 2,
   "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
   "config": {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.container.image.v1+json",
      "size": 2090,
      "digest": "sha256:1111111111"
   },
   "layers": [
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
         "size": 642909,
         "digest": "sha256:2222222222"
      },
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
         "size": 8089565,
         "digest": "sha256:3333333333"
      },
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
         "size": 49,
         "digest": "sha256:4444444444"
      },
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
         "size": 7966397,
         "digest": "sha256:5555555555"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Where did this JSON file come from?  How are you trying to use it?  Kubernetes all but requires an image registry of some sort (like Docker Hub or Amazon's ECR) and you should not need to try to manipulate images as files.  In particular there's almost never any need for `docker import` in any context.

Comment: @DavidMaze this JSON is part of the directory that contains the files mentioned. It is actually an Artifactory type repo. But they were used in a different context in another cloud. What I know is that this directory contains all the application files needed to deploy on EKS. I can't figure out how to push and pull all these together from AWS ECR.

Comment: You should be able to point Kubernetes directly at Artifactory; something like `image: artifactory.example.com/repository:tag`.  This file isn't used in any visible way.

Comment: @DavidMaze actually I don't have access to the Artifactory repo. I need to rely solely on ECR. But I might be able to do that in ECR as well.